# How to Login diffrent user in same browser Tab?

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, session-state

I am working on a web application by using ASP.NET C#. I have maintain the User Login by Session state. I want to Login diffrent user in same browser Tab. Is it possible? How can I Login diffrent user in same browser Tab ?

Thanks
Nahid

Comment: Please explain better what you want. It is by default not possible to have multiple sessions per browser (or per tab), since the session ID is kept in a cookie that gets sent on every request.

Comment: I want to Login by diffrent diffrent user in same browser Tab. suppose, my Session["User_ID"] will be different,  Session["User_Name"] will be diffrent.

Comment: Hello CodeCaster, Thanks for your reply. can you explain "session ID is kept in a cookie that gets sent on every request".

Comment: as I said, that is not possible. Why would you want to do that? How can a user be logged on as two users at the same time? Do you want to share some privileges? Why not log the first user out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is only one Session state available to an ASP.NET app.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can't log same web application different accounts in same browser tabs. you should have to use different browsers

Answer (score 1):

The authentication ticket is hold in one cookie, and the cookie are share/common among all tabs or windows in the same browser, and there are not other way.

**So there is only one login possible for the same browser**.

Other possible solutions:

**note:** Only for controlled environment on office, not for the public view :) This not for let it on Internet and expect to be followed. For the general users the answer is again that is not possible.

1. Open in the same browser a new incognito window, you can have one more login.
2. Run other browsers, to hold other logins.
3. Run the same browser under different user account together.

To run the same browser under different user account, make a short cut of your browser, right click on shortcut go to advanced, check the "Run with different credentials" and when you click on this icon its ask to login with a different user, and the browser runs in a different parameters.

Comment: No, no, no. These are all silly workarounds (not all work places support the user to run under a different user, not all PC's have multiple users, not all browsers have an incognito mode, not everyone wants to or can install another browser) for a problem that has not yet been fully described. Perhaps the client's only requirement was _"User A should be able to see the documents of User B"_, and user A also logging in as user B was OP's answer to that problem. Which it isn't.

Comment: @CodeCaster There are not silly, I make them many times especial on development. If the UserA need to read the documents of UserB this is something else and can be solve inside the program, but is not what is ask here.

Comment: yes, it's perfectly valid for development purposes. But you're not going to tell your clients "Use Google Chrome to log in as user A, user Firefox to log in as user B and user IE for user C". You cannot and will not even think of such things being a "solution", especially since the underlying problem has not been told (expect for "Its my client requirement", which I sincerely doubt).

Comment: @CodeCaster Of course this are silly if they expect to be use on an uncontrolled environment. I think that they need to be use limited for from the boss on backoffice, or something similar.